# Stripe connect: how to keep funds more than 90 days?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm developing and application with stripe connect. It's required that an user **S** can send funds to a stripe connect managed account user **MA**. It's necessary that those funds remain in the **MA** Stripe account for more than 90 days, but the documentation says that this is not possible: [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts)

Am I missing something? Is the only possible solution to have user **S** send funds to the App bank account via Stripe and then when necessary transfer those funds to the **MA** stripe account? Because I think this is not a clear approach.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was missing something.
For you guys in the far future, this is how you do it: [Stripe Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfers)

Comment: But then are the money marked as yours until you transfer those to the users account?

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken with stripe support about this.

Because separate charges and transfers are not available in some countries, another method would be to check if the date is greater than 90 days. If it is than you do not charge the card. Instead, you [save the card](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later). Then using some kind of scheduled cron job, charge the card in the future when it is less than 90 days from payout. Use [manual payout](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts) to payout the funds within the 90 day limit.

Hope this helps